# problems with print loop in R

Tags: r

I write a loop like this:

```
n<-3
for(i in 1:n-1)
{
print(c("i= "))
print(c(i))
}
```

And I want to print `i=1, 2`
but the result of this code is `i=0, 1, 2`
What's wrong of the result?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add brackets here in the for loop: `1:(n-1)`. Without the brackets, you are taking `1:n` = 1,2,3 and subtracting 1 from each of them.

You may also want `print(paste("i=", i))`.